# why this line : man_1.print(emps) doesn't have any output in python 3.8

Tags: python

```
class Manager(Employee) :
    def __init__(self,first,last,pay,prog_lang,employees=None) :
        super().__init__(first,last,pay)
        if employees is None :
            self.employees = []
        else :
            self.employees = employees


    def add_emps(self,emps) :
        if emps not in self.employees :
            self.employees.append(emps)

    def rem_emps(self,emps) :
        if emps in self.employees :
            self.employees.remove(emps)

    def print_emps(self) :
        for emps in self.employees :
            print('-->',emps.full_name())

dev_1 = Developer('corey','schafer',50000,'python')
dev_2 = Developer('elham','zeinodini',222000,'java')


man_1 = Manager('elham','zeinodini',20000,[dev_1]) 


# why this line :  man_1.print(emps)  doesn't have any output in python 3.8 
man_1.print_emps()
```

Comment: So what is the `prog_lang` argument to `__init__` for?

Comment: also another tip, why are you setting the default value for `employees` to `None` instead of just `[]` in the constructor? I think the `if .. else` block is just unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Manager instance, the `[dev_1]` parameter value is actually the `prog_lang` parameter from `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

`self.employees` is empty, which you should have checked before posting here.

You sent in the one employee as a programming language, and threw away the value.

```
def print_emps(self) :
    print(f'employees {self.employees}')
    for emps in self.employees :
        print('-->',emps.full_name())
```

Result:

```
employees []
```

Replace your construction with the proper values:

```
 man_1 = Manager('elham', 'zeinodini', 20000, "Excel", [dev_1])
```